# How to prevent Kendo Grid click propagation

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I need to add an image to one specific column, so I have something like that, This is good, I see the image, I just added am alert to see how is working. My problem is that after showing the alert, is executing the sorting. Is there a way to avoid the sorting when I just click on my image?

```
{
    field: "ShipName", headerTemplate: "<a class='k-link pull-left' href='#'>Charge</a><img onclick='alert(1)' src='http://localhost/MyApp/images/Reports/filterApplied.png' title='this is a filter'/>",
    title: "Ship Name"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want that particular column to sort, then disable it in your grid's configuration. [API Reference](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#configuration-columns.sortable).

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `return false;`, which works like [e.preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/):

```
onclick='alert(1); return false;'
```

Comment: is there any other possible solution?